# Probability of $\limsup_n\left\{|\frac{\max_{1\leq k \leq n}X_k}{\ln(n)}-1| >\epsilon\right\}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables and identically distributed, following the exponential distribution with parameter 1.

Let $0<\epsilon<1.$ I want to compute $P\left(\limsup_n\left\{\left|\frac{\max_{1\leq k \leq n}X_k}{\ln(n)}-1\right| >\epsilon\right\}\right)$

I am thankful for any idea.

Comment: Let $M_n$ be the max, you can first write the condition $|M_n/\log(n)-1|>\epsilon$ in terms of two inequalities. You want the probability that occurs for infinitely many $n$, you can just work with one inequality first.

Comment: I did that and then I tried to use Borel-Cantelli Lemma, but it doesn't worl since $\sum_n P(\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}}{ln(n)}<1-\epsilon)=\sum_n(1-\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}})=+\infty$ but $\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}}{ln(n)}$ aren't independent

Comment: It should be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}})^n$.  So, you are forgetting to raise to the power $n$.

Comment: yet the series doesn't converges

Comment: $$
\left(1-1/n^{1-\epsilon}\right)^n = e^{n \ln(1-1/n^{1-\epsilon}) }
= e^{-n^{\epsilon}+o(n^{\epsilon}) }
$$
so the series *will* converge, e.g., by comparison with $\sum_n e^{-n^{\epsilon/2}}$.  @mathex

Comment: I mean what about the other we have $\sum_nP(\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k}{ln(n)}>\epsilon+1)=\sum_n(1-(1-\frac{1}{n^{\epsilon+1}})^n)$

Comment: It doesn't converges if $0<\epsilon<1$

Comment: I don't have much time, so just to check: are you sure you are using the right CDF when trying to apply the Borel-Cantelli Lemma? How do you get that quantity (for both upper and lower bound) to begin with?

Comment: If we set $Y_n=\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k$, we have $F_{Y_n}(x)=(F_{X_1}(x))^n,$ so $P(|\frac{Y_n}{ln}-1|>\epsilon)=1-F_{Y_n}(\epsilon+1)+F_{Y_n}(1-\epsilon)=1+(1-1/n^{1-\epsilon})^n-(1-1/n^{1+\epsilon})^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Claim

Let $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d. exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda=1$. Define $M_n = \max_{\{k : 1 \leq k \leq n\}}X_k$.  Then:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{M_n}{\log(n)} = 1 \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} $$

#### Derivation

Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Then
$$ \{|M_n/\log(n) - 1| > \epsilon\} = \underbrace{\{\{M_n < \log(n^{1-\epsilon})\}}_{\mbox{type 1}} \cup \underbrace{\{M_n> \log(n^{1+\epsilon})\}}_{\mbox{type 2}}   $$

#### Set Type 1:

Indeed $P[M_n < \log(n^{1-\epsilon})]= (1-\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}})^n \approx exp(-n^\epsilon)$. This is summable (as Clement C notes above) and so by Borel-Cantelli we can conclude that, with prob 1, at most finitely many of the events $\{M_n < \log(n^{1-\epsilon})\}$ occur.

#### Set Type 2:

Indeed $P[M_n > \log(n^{1+\epsilon})] = 1-(1-\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}})^n$.  This case is more tricky since indeed these are not summable over all $n$.  Nevertheless there is a nice technique of summing over the sparse subsequence of indices of the form $2^k$:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P\left[M_{2^k}>\log\left((2^k)^{1+\epsilon}\right)\right] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{(2^k)^{1+\epsilon}}\right)^{2^k}\right] $$
This sum is not trivial to evaluate, but indeed it is finite.

Wait a minute, you say, what about the $M_n$ values for indices $n$ that are *not* powers of 2? Well,  for any $n$ that satisfies $2^k \leq  n \leq 2^{k+1}$ we can say:
$$ \frac{M_n}{\log(n)} \leq \frac{M_{2^{k+1}}}{\log(2^k)}$$
So 
$$ \cup_{\{n : 2^k\leq n \leq 2^{k+1}\}}\left\{\frac{M_n}{\log(n)}>1+\epsilon\right\} \subseteq \left\{ \frac{M_{2^{k+1}}}{\log(2^k)} > 1+\epsilon\right\} $$
so it remains to compute 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P\left[\frac{M_{2^{k+1}}}{\log(2^k)}>1+\epsilon \right] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k(1+\epsilon)}}\right)^{2^{k+1}} \right]$$
This sum is similar to the previous one and is also finite.

So, with prob 1, at most finitely many type 2 events occur.